# Using Visual Studio Immediate Window like VBA immediate window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, immediate-window

In the VBA immediate window, I can simply type the following at any time:

```
?Len("Four")
```

Press enter and get the result:

```
4
```

If I try to do that in Visual Studio Express (VB.NET), I get the following result:

```
The name 'Len' does not exist in the current context
```

I assume it has to do with VBA being a "scripting" language and VB.Net requiring compilation.  I'm just looking for a simple way to evaluate expressions using functions from the built-in libraries.

Comment: what version of VB.net/Visual Studio?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new console app and tested both

```
?"Four".Length
```

and

```
?Len("Four")
```

both of which result in `4`, after my project has run.

Do you have a project that will run? The immediate window needs to be evaluated in the context of a running project. If so,

Have you imported `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your project properties "References" tab? If I remove that I get,

> 'Len' is not declared. It may be inaccesible due to its protection level.

But, the `Length` propery of `System.String` still works because I'm still importing `System`.

Comment: "Do you have a project that will run? The immediate window needs to be evaluated in the context of a running project."  This seems to be the key bit of info I was missing.  Creating a new console app seems to be the simplest solution if all I want to do is evaluate some expressions in the immediate window.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are currently stepping through your code.

Comment: This is not a requirement in VBA.  Is this a requirement in VB.Net/Visual Studio?

Comment: This is it.  Apparently the VS vhost has to actually be in the running state first.

Comment: It appears that Visual Studio will attempt to enter a running state automatically in some scenarios.  Using @Jodrell's example of creating a new console application, I can then evaluate expressions in the immediate window without explicitly stepping through the code.  VS will run the application even if the code consists of only the stock `Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    End Sub

End Module`